# Spatial heatmap Legend Mismatch. Leaflet, R

Tags: r, heatmap, r-leaflet

I'm trying to create a heatmap in Leaflet using `addHeatmap()` from `leaflet.extras` using the following example data:

```
set.seed(123)

testdf <- data.frame(
  lng = runif(100, min=93.2, max=94.3),
  lat = runif(100, min=20, max=22),
  var = sample(0:39, 100, replace=TRUE)
  )
```

I want the color to represent a variable from the data and so set the `intensity` argument to that variable.

I have added a legend but it doesn't seem like the legend is matching up to the values.

My code is as follows:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
pal <- c('#003366','#0066d1','#00ced1','#007300','#00ff00','#ffd700','#ffa500','#ff1a1a','#8e0000')

leaflet(data=testdf) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~lng,
                   ~lat,
                   radius = 4,
                   stroke = FALSE,
                   fillOpacity=1,
                   popup = ~paste(var)) %>%
  addHeatmap(lng =~lng,
             lat=~lat,
             gradient=pal,
             intensity=~var,
             blur = 60,
             minOpacity = 1
             ) %>% 
  addLegend(pal=colorNumeric(pal, domain=testdf$var),
          values=testdf$var)
```

I think this is the result of one of the following:

- Conflict with the `gradient` argument?
- Incorrect use of the color function in `addLegend()`?
- My lack of understanding how the heatmap should function?

Am I making some obvious error somewhere? I'm new to heatmaps and so I'm a bit unsure.

Help appreciated!